# Regex to capture everything before specific string and then progressively

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

A. `if specific_condition then specific_function`

This is the longest variation of the string and it could also occur in the following ways:

B. `if specific_function then`

C. `if specific_function`

`specific_condition` is analogous to a multi-word string e.g. my name is obi. So a fully defined string could be `if my name is obi then doFunction()`;

I have the following regex:

```
/(if) *(.*?)(?=then|$)(then) *(.*)/
```

which would match:

```
if specific_condition then specific_function
if specific_condition then
```

but it wouldn't match:

```
if specific_condition
```

What I want to do is come up with a regex that would match all the string variations and also capture relevant groups:

1. If I have string C., it would match and also capture `{1}=if` and `{2}=specific_condition`
2. If I have string B., it would match and also capture `{1}=if`, `{2}=specific_condition`, and `{3}=then`
3. If I have string A., it would match and also capture `{1}=if`, `{2}=specific_condition`, `{3}=then`, and `{4}=specific_function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

`"if specific_function then specific_function".match(/(if) *(.*?)(?=then|$)(?:(then) *(.*))?/)`

`"if specific_function then".match(/(if) *(.*?)(?=then|$)(?:(then) *(.*))?/)`

`"if specific_function".match(/(if) *(.*?)(?=then|$)(?:(then) *(.*))?/)`

http://jsfiddle.net/cqebLv4h/

Comment: It matches only 2 of the string variations?!

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question for more clarity. I was using RegexBuddy earlier, but I hadn't enabled the option `^$ match at linebreaks`. When I did everything worked. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`/(if) *(.*?) (then)? *(.*)/`

I tested by online regex testers and all of your 3 expression were matched.

Comment: it also matches

`"if specific_function specific_function".match(/(if) *(.*?)(?=then|$)(?:(then) *(.*))?/)`

4th argument... that I don't think should be matched... but I'm not sure

Comment: I edited the question for more clarity. This doesn't capture the groups properly. For example, when using 'if my name is obi then doSomething()' I get `{1}=if`, `{2}=my`, and `{4}=name is obi then doSomething()`